# I can't create a user in Amazon Cognito user pool from an AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-vpc

I have an Amazon Cognito user pool and a Lambda function from which I would like to create users in Amazon Cognito user pool. I have the following Lambda code.

```
  const userPoolId = 'eu-north-…;
  const clientId = '…';
  const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ 
    region: 'eu-north-1' 
  });

  const userAttributes = [
    {
      Name: 'email',
      Value: email,
    },
  ];


  const params = {
    UserPoolId: userPoolId,
    Username: email, // Use email as the username
    UserAttributes: userAttributes,
    MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS', // Do not send a welcome message
    DesiredDeliveryMediums: ['EMAIL'], // Send an email invitation
  };

  cognito.adminCreateUser(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
  });
```

When I run the code, I do not get any error. However it is strange that none of the branches of the adminCreateUser's function is executed.

I have an IAM role assigned to the Lambda. The role has the AmazonCognitoPowerUser and AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole policies.

I have a VPC with subnets. The outbound rules of the connected security group is type: HTTPS, protocol: TCP, port: 443 Destination: 0.0.0.0/0.
I have a MYSQL type security group rule as well (in order to reach RDS). In that case the destination is set to the security group. I tried to set the destination of my HTTPS rule to the same security group, but I got an error message.
Is this security group rule appropriate?

In the route table I have two entries of outbound rules:

Destination 0.0.0.0/0, Target: igw-…

destination: x.x.x.x/16, Target: local

The same Lambda function can access Amazon RDS database without any problem. Apart from the security group outbound rules, there is no RDS specific settings.

I have also checked the CloudTrail. The UpdateFunctionCode within the EventHistory shows the role and CPC config among the responseElements. They are correct.

What else shall I set for reaching Amazon Cognito?
How can I make sure the Lambda code is effective and there is some issue with the VPC configuration?

Thanks in advance for your help.